# loss of data integrity when consuming incoming FIX market messages using ActionBlock and/or Channel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, channel, fix-protocol

I  use [epam's FIX engine](https://github.com/epam/fix-antenna-net-core) in an application to communicate via FIX.  The method via which the incoming FIX messages arrive is an inherited `void OnNewMessage(FixMessage msg)` method. From there I want to consume the `msg`, offloading to a worker (threadpool?) thread to do CPU bound calculations. That is after doing a quick `msg` sorting check or two to see if an incoming `msg` is of interest or not.

Taking into account, as mentioned on the github repo `Note: The IFixSessionListener.OnNewMessage() method must not be dead-locked or perform time-demanding operations because it will lock all message processing for this session. A user should execute time consuming handling operations in separate threads and return control as soon as possible..` Therefore I want to offload as fast as possible.

I get the error or problem that Tag 268 does not exist, which in reality it does exists because I can see it in the FIX messages when looking at the incoming FIX message log.

I started testing with [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-8.0) and  [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-8.0) to try and fix this loss of data integrity which I presume happens due to threading (`Task.Run`). As I understand, `ActionBlock` and `Channel` is there for built in thread safety, parallelism or concurrency.

Channel code:

```
private readonly Channel<FixMessagePlusID> _fixChannel;
private readonly ChannelReader<FixMessagePlusID> reader;
private readonly ChannelWriter<FixMessagePlusID> writer;
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _ctSource;
private readonly CancellationToken _token;

_ctSource =  new CancellationTokenSource();
_token = _ctSource.Token;
_fixChannel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<FixMessagePlusID>();
reader = _fixChannel.Reader;
writer =  _fixChannel.Writer;
int id = 0;

Task consumerOne =  StartConsumingAsync();
Task consumerTwo =  StartConsumingAsync();

public async void OnNewMessage(FixMessage fixMessage)
{
    int repeating = fixMessage.GetTagAsInt(268);
    Console.WriteLine("Tag 268 capture as: " + repeating.ToString() + " MsgID: "  + id.ToString());
    if(StartUsingData)
    {               
        await writer.WriteAsync(new FixMessagePlusID(fixMessage,id), _token);
        id++;
        if(id > 10){ StartUsingData = false; }  
    }
}
public async Task StartConsumingAsync()
{
    await foreach (var fixMessagePlusID in reader.ReadAllAsync(_token))
    {
        FixMessage fixMessage = fixMessagePlusID.FixMessage;
        if(fixMessage.IsTagExists(268))
        {
            int repeating = fixMessage.GetTagAsInt(268);
            if(repeating == 1)
            {                               
                string symbol = fixMessage.GetTagValueAsString(55);
                if(IWantToUseThisMessage)
                {
                    // Do long running CPU bound task:
                    DoWork());
                }
            }   
        }
        else{Console.WriteLine("Msg Tag268 FAIL, MsgID: " + fixMessagePlusID.ID);}
    }
}
```

EDIT:

See the updated code example and console result screenshot below.  Tag 268 IS found before it is written to the Channel.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with Channels or ActionBlock. Are you sure the tag exists in this particular FixMessage instance? You're logging only the exception, not the message that caused it

Comment: The code is definitely wrong though. `StartConsumingAsync` is already running in a separate thread, there's no need for `await Task.Run()`. This just blocks the worker thread while waiting for another thread to complete. `OnMessage` posts *all* message types to the block, including I suspect control messages

Comment: Yes sure all the message have tag 268 in them -- all message give the response that tag 268 does not exist. Every few milliseconds constantly.

Noted  on your second point about `await Task.Run()` - thanks. However the problem I do not understand  occurs before the workflow gets to that point right?

Comment: Tag 268 is a count tag for a repeating group, though. Not any experience with their FIX engine but maybe you need to check for the tag differently?

Comment: @ChristophJohn, that is a consideration. Although Tag 268 does not repeat itself. But good point - going to look into that further.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, added the Channel code example as well.

Comment: @ChristophJohn, please see after the edit. The `IsTagExists()` works before the writing to channel

Comment: OK, I'm afraid I cannot help you further here since I don't know ePAM's FIX engine at all.